# What's the point of using "x$START_DAEMON" = "xyes" here? (the leading x)

Tags: bash, test

This was part of a fetchmail daemon script,

`if [ ! "x$START_DAEMON" = "xyes" -a ! "$1" = "status" ]; then`

What's the point of using `x$START_DAEMON = "xyes"`; why not just use `$START_DAEMON = "yes"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen cases where the `x$variable` was *not* quoted, and in that case it's to handle situations where the variable (`$START_DAEMON` in this case) might be empty.  Otherwise, your test would be checking whether `! = "yes"`, and the test would error. However, as you've pointed out in comments, double-quoting the `x$variable` takes care of this.

On the other hand, a question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/7503/how-to-determine-if-a-bash-variable-is-empty) led me to this page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html, wherein one is preventing the variable expansion from starting with a character that may confuse `[` or `test`

Even so, I think this is an issue that may only be a problem in older ("Historical" as the opengroup page says) shells, and that newer implementations do the right thing without the `x`, so long as double-quotes are involved at least.  So it may primarily be a coding tradition.  I was able to confirm a problem using `/bin/sh` on SunOS 5.10, though:

```
 # a="!"; [ "$a" = "yes" ] && echo ok
 test: argument expected
```

Comment: `unset a;[ "$a" = "yes" ] && echo ok` that doesn't report error, hmm

Comment: Right you are.  I have seen cases where `x$variable` was not quoted, and it may have been those situations where problems with `test` arose.  However, using a known character like `x` does prevent other problems with special characters -- I'll update the answer.

Comment: It can also be a shell quoting issue. For example, Bash 4.2.24 complains `bash: !: event not found` with your posted example, but avoids history expansion and works fine with `a=\!; [[ "$a" = "yes" ]] && echo ok` instead.

Comment: POSIX mandates the parsing of all correct `test` expressions up to three tokens, such as this one. Historical Bourne shells are buggy. The `x` prefix makes the left-to-right parsing unambiguous. The double quotes are necessary in any shell, in case the value of the variable is empty, contains spaces, etc. The double quotes aren't necessary inside `[[…]]` which is special syntax, not a mere built-in utility like `[`.